# i use ubuntu 14.04 there are big problems with fileinputstream,fileoutputstream?

Tags: java, ubuntu, bufferedreader, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and am experiencing problems with `FileInputStream`, `FileOutputStream`, `BufferedReader`, and `BufferWriter`
Here is my project. When I try to copy data from one file to another file there is problem
Code:

```
try{
    File filename=new File(jttex1.getText());
    File nfile=new File(jttex2.getText());
    if(!filename.exists()){
        p("file is not found");
        return;
    }
    if(!nfile.exists()){
        p("file is not found");
        return;
    } 

    FileInputStream vinput=new FileInputStream(filename);
    FileOutputStream voutput=new FileOutputStream(nfile);  
    jsizee.setText("size"+vinput.available());
    byte[] buffer=new byte [50];
    int lenghtt=0;

    while ((vinput.read(buffer)) > 0);{
        voutput.write(buffer);
        vinput.close();
        voutput.close();
    }
}catch(IOException ee){
    System.err.println(ee.getMessage());

}
}
```

> There was problem when opening txt file   file
>   "/home/mizzz/netbeansprojects/fold2/fg2.txt" the file you opened has
>   some invalid characters if you continue this file corrupt this
>   document  you can also choose another character encoding and try again
>
> /00/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/ 00/00/00/

Comment: Your file is full of nulls.  You also don't specify where you're reading it *from*.

Comment: This code is so odd, I can't even.

Comment: i ask if this problem from my codes or my ubuntu?

Comment: No, that code is completely wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Your loop is completely wrong. You should read some IO tutorials.

```
while ((vinput.read(buffer)) > 0);{
        voutput.write(buffer);
        vinput.close();
        voutput.close();}
```

Should be

```
int bytes = 0;
while((bytes = vinput.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    voutput.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
}
vinput.close();
voutput.close();
```

Comment: Now go read those tutorials. This is a very basic and well known pattern. If you intend to keep on programming you need to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no outstanding problems with Java file I/O on Ubuntu (or other platforms).

The problem is in your code. Just use the [`copy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) method:

```
Path src = Paths.get(jttex1.getText());
Path dst = Paths.get(jttex2.getText());
jsizee.setText("size: " + Files.size(src));
Files.copy(src, dst);
```

If you insist on reading all the data into user space (a byte array in your Java code), then you'll need to open and close the files properly. That would look more like this:

```
Path src = Paths.get(jttex1.getText());
Path dst = Paths.get(jttex2.getText());
try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(src)) {
  byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
  try (OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(dst)) {
    while (true) {
      int n = is.read(buffer);
      if (n < 0)
        break;
      os.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
  }
}
```